# logging with info level in play framework 2.0.3 for java using play logger

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I would like to control the logging by configuring log level in logger.xml.

I used play.Logger with level ERROR set in logger.xml but logger with level INFO, DEBGU are also getting logged.

I have used **ALogger log = play.Logger.of(Application.class);**  with INFO level in logger.xml but only error logs are getting logged.

I tried creating the custom logger class also by having custom methods for info and debug but it didn't work out.

I have not found any solution in any of the forum/community pages. Please guide me how to proceed further.

Below is the code & also the logger.xml

```
package test

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.index;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Rendering "));
    }

    public static Result ourApp() {
        ALogger log = play.Logger.of(Application.class);
        log.info("**** Info enabled *****");
        log.debug("**** debug enabled *****");
        log.error("**** error enabled *****");
        if(log.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            log.debug("**** Debug enabled *****");
        }
        if(log.isInfoEnabled())
        {
            log.info("**** Info enabled *****");
        }
        if(log.isErrorEnabled())
        {
            log.error("**** Error enabled *****");
        }
        return ok();
    }

    public static Result getXPage(String patId) {
        String xValue = TestDao.getXNotes(patId);
        return ok(test.render(Value));
    }
}
```

**logger.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/app.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date - [%level] - %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

   <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

**Output:-**

```
2012-11-22 19:05:43,920 - [INFO] - from play 
Application started (Dev)

2012-11-22 19:05:44,127 - [ERROR] - from test.Application 
**** error enabled *****
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the logger name instead of the Class name

```
ALogger log = play.Logger.of("application");
```

This wokrs fine. Also comment out the lines that mention the log level in the file `application.conf`

Comment: One can just use for this: play.Logger#info(java.lang.String). The problem is this will not print classname from which u are logging the class.Prints `play.Logger$ALogger - 2016-10-02 01:19:47,684 - abcxyz my application logs`

Answer (score 0):

I stuck on the same issue and also it didn't print actual line number and class name of my log, after long search i found this [project](https://github.com/studiodev/play2-log-subproject) on git-hub and tried the `sl4j` logger like following and it works.

**Controller**

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("controller");
```

**Logger.xml**

`<logger name="controller" level="DEBUG" />`

Finally commented out all the log levels in `application.conf`.